# Release memory for fitted model training data

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

To make [Ordinal Classification](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/ordinal_tech_report.pdf), I have to use scikit-learn's `clone`.
But `clone` method makes a **huge waste of memory**!

**How can I release memory for only data part of each model?**

Here is a sample code.

```
import gc
import os
import sys
import psutil
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.base import clone

p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
X = np.random.normal(size=(10000, 50))
Y = np.floor(np.random.rand(10000)*10)


def print_mem():
    print("{:.0f}MB".format(p.memory_info().rss / 1e6))

print_mem()
my_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, max_features=1, n_jobs=28)

models = []
for i in np.sort(np.array(list(set(Y)))):
    if i != max(set(Y)):
        model = clone(my_model)
        model.fit(X, Y > i)
        models.append(model)
        gc.collect()
        print_mem()
print(sys.getsizeof(models[0])/1e3, " KB / model")
```

Output:

```
102MB
313MB
602MB
953MB
1346MB
1752MB
2139MB
2488MB
2708MB
2872MB
0.056  KB / model
```

System Info:

```
Linux-4.10.0-28-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0]
NumPy 1.13.3
SciPy 0.19.1
Scikit-Learn 0.19.1
```

Comment: What do you mean by data part of the model? You are appending the model to a list so each model will be stored and memory will increase.

Comment: If I increase the size of `X` 10 times, then the memory usage of each model is also increased 10 times. This means each model copy the data and store it **somewhere**, and I want to release the memory in that **somewhere**.